# Mouseover or onclick event not working on scatterPlot in dc.js

Tags: javascript, dc.js

I am using dc.js library 3.0.12 based on d3.js 5.9.2 for a scatterplot.

The scatterplot has been generated as my expectation. My next step is to add some mouseover or on click event to the points to help users get additional information from my data.

I have referred and adapted some code from these two questions:

[dc.js onClick Listener Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24642675/dc-js-onclick-listener-not-working)

[show additional data properties on mouseover in dc.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48926817/show-additional-data-properties-on-mouseover-in-dc-js)

By checking the elements on the scatterplot, it seems to me that the scatter points on the plot can be reached by accessing "path.symbol"

Because it is really hard to isolate the data from my own page, I generated some fake data for the plotting and following is the code I have tried (with two different methods):

```
var people = [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Damaris",
    "gender": "Female",
    "DOB": "1973-02-18",
    "MaritalStatus": "false",
    "CreditCardType": "visa-electron",
    "y":12
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Barbe",
    "gender": "Female",
    "DOB": "1969-04-10",
    "MaritalStatus": "true",
    "CreditCardType": "americanexpress",
    "y":14
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Belia",
    "gender": "Female",
    "DOB": "1960-04-16",
    "MaritalStatus": "false",
    "CreditCardType": "maestro",
    "y":8
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Leoline",
    "gender": "Female",
    "DOB": "1995-01-19",
    "MaritalStatus": "true",
    "CreditCardType": "bankcard",
    "y":20
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "Valentine",
    "gender": "Female",
    "DOB": "1992-04-16",
    "MaritalStatus": "false",
    "CreditCardType": "",
    "y":16
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "name": "Rosanne",
    "gender": "Female",
    "DOB": "1985-01-05",
    "MaritalStatus": "true",
    "CreditCardType": "bankcard",
    "y":22
  },
  {
    "id": 7,
    "name": "Shalna",
    "gender": "Female",
    "DOB": "1956-11-01",
    "MaritalStatus": "false",
    "CreditCardType": "jcb",
    "y":15
  },
  {
    "id": 8,
    "name": "Mordy",
    "gender": "Male",
    "DOB": "1990-03-27",
    "MaritalStatus": "true",
    "CreditCardType": "china-unionpay",
    "y":6
  },
  {
    "id": 9,
    "name": "Tristan",
    "gender": "Male",
    "DOB": "1998-10-05",
    "MaritalStatus": "true",
    "CreditCardType": "",
    "y":21
  },
  {
    "id": 10,
    "name": "Alphonso",
    "gender": "Male",
    "DOB": "1992-08-10",
    "MaritalStatus": "false",
    "CreditCardType": "mastercard",
    "y":12
  },
  {
    "id": 11,
    "name": "Hirsch",
    "gender": "Male",
    "DOB": "1973-02-13",
    "MaritalStatus": "false",
    "CreditCardType": "",
    "y":6
  },
  {
    "id": 12,
    "name": "Kirstyn",
    "gender": "Female",
    "DOB": "1989-06-28",
    "MaritalStatus": "false",
    "CreditCardType": "bankcard",
    "y":15
  },
  {
    "id": 13,
    "name": "Benson",
    "gender": "Male",
    "DOB": "1959-10-19",
    "MaritalStatus": "true",
    "CreditCardType": "switch",
    "y":14
  },
  {
    "id": 14,
    "name": "Florry",
    "gender": "Female",
    "DOB": "1993-11-11",
    "MaritalStatus": "true",
    "CreditCardType": "diners-club-international",
    "y":8
  },
  {
    "id": 15,
    "name": "Jenine",
    "gender": "Female",
    "DOB": "1957-02-16",
    "MaritalStatus": "false",
    "CreditCardType": "diners-club-enroute",
    "y":21
  },
  {
    "id": 16,
    "name": "Hortense",
    "gender": "Female",
    "DOB": "1993-12-17",
    "MaritalStatus": "false",
    "CreditCardType": "jcb",
    "y":17
  },
  {
    "id": 17,
    "name": "Zulema",
    "gender": "Female",
    "DOB": "1990-09-27",
    "MaritalStatus": "false",
    "CreditCardType": "jcb",
    "y":18
  },
  {
    "id": 18,
    "name": "Leoline",
    "gender": "Female",
    "DOB": "1990-02-02",
    "MaritalStatus": "false",
    "CreditCardType": "visa-electron",
    "y":8
  },
  {
    "id": 19,
    "name": "Bayard",
    "gender": "Male",
    "DOB": "1997-01-11",
    "MaritalStatus": "false",
    "CreditCardType": "jcb",
    "y":15
  },
  {
    "id": 20,
    "name": "Joanne",
    "gender": "Female",
    "DOB": "1996-02-01",
    "MaritalStatus": "false",
    "CreditCardType": "maestro",
    "y":19
  },
  {
    "id": 21,
    "name": "Marlee",
    "gender": "Female",
    "DOB": "1994-11-28",
    "MaritalStatus": "false",
    "CreditCardType": "",
    "y":13.7
  },
  {
    "id": 22,
    "name": "Mitchell",
    "gender": "Male",
    "DOB": "1993-03-09",
    "MaritalStatus": "false",
    "CreditCardType": "maestro",
    "y":21
  },
  {
    "id": 23,
    "name": "Jefferey",
    "gender": "Male",
    "DOB": "1999-09-19",
    "MaritalStatus": "false",
    "CreditCardType": "jcb",
    "y":30
  },
  {
    "id": 24,
    "name": "Jolee",
    "gender": "Female",
    "DOB": "1951-04-14",
    "MaritalStatus": "false",
    "CreditCardType": "jcb",
    "y":30.5
  },
  {
    "id": 25,
    "name": "Selma",
    "gender": "Female",
    "DOB": "1958-08-14",
    "MaritalStatus": "false",
    "CreditCardType": "mastercard",
    "y":26.9
  },
  {
    "id": 26,
    "name": "Pavlov",
    "gender": "Male",
    "DOB": "1971-12-24",
    "MaritalStatus": "true",
    "CreditCardType": "jcb",
    "y":29.4
  }
]

var mycrossfilter = crossfilter(people);

var ageDimension = mycrossfilter.dimension(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  return [~~((Date.now() - new Date(data.DOB)) / (31557600000))]
});
var yDimension = mycrossfilter.dimension(function(d){return d.y;})
var trialDimension = mycrossfilter.dimension(function(d){return [+d.y,[ + ~~((Date.now() - new Date(d.DOB)) / (31557600000))]] });
var trialGroup = trialDimension.group()
var chart = dc.scatterPlot('#scatter');


chart
  .width(300)
  .height(800)
  .brushOn(true)
  .x(d3.scaleLinear().domain([10, 40]))
  .y(d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 70]))
  .yAxisLabel("Count")
  .xAxisLabel("Age")
  .dimension(ageDimension)
  .group(trialGroup)

chart.render();

console.log(d3.selectAll('path.symbol'));

//Trial 1

 chart.on("renderlet.chart", function(chart){
    chart.selectAll('path.symbol').on('click',function(){alert("Hello! It works");});
  });

// Trial 2

  d3.select('body').on('click', function(){
    d3.selectAll('path.symbol').on('mouseover',function(){alert("Hello! It works");});
  });
```

I also set up a jsfiddle with the same code to help reproduce my problem as well, with the link https://jsfiddle.net/Binny92/eysua84q/

However, neither of the two trials worked in my case. No matter what and where I clicked, I got no expected response at all. It seems as if I have never succeeded in clicking any of the points. But when I ran d3.selectAll('path.symbol') separately, the browser was returning me an object with _group. of selected nodes. I couldn't figure out why the event action is not working and am looking forward to any suggestion about the issue.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have `brushOn(true)` so the [d3.brush](https://github.com/d3/d3-brush/blob/v1.1.2/README.md#brush) overlay will intercepts all mouse events.

You can see this by right-clicking a dot and inspecting it in the developer tools:

[image: inspect brush overlay]

Instead of inspecting a symbol as we'd expect (or the svg element if we missed it), we hit a rect object. This is probably why @Wolfetto suggested selecting this instead. But it's not what we want, because if we receive mouseover or click events on the symbols, the events will include the dot data.

If you don't want 2D brushing you could do `brushOn(false)`.

But if you want it all, you could move the brush overlay to behind the points. Users might find it confusing that they can only brush on the background, but at least the cursor changes to show what will happen. In my fork of your fiddle I changed the cursor to `pointer` when it's over a symbol and that makes the difference clearer.

To move the overlay to the back, add this line to the renderlet handler:

```
chart.g().node().insertBefore(chart.select('g.brush').node(), chart.select('g.chart-body').node())
```

Yeah, that's a bit too many `.node()`s - we're just using D3 to select nodes, but the browser's [insertBefore](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore) to actually move the brush before (behind) the chart body.

[Fork of your fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/qstvbwde/29/)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer and the library, it really helps. Now I see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing wrong value inside `chart.selectAll` function

Replace the function:

```
 chart.on("renderlet.chart", function(chart){
      chart.selectAll('path.symbol').on('click',function(){
        alert("Hello! It works");
      });
  });
```

with:

```
chart.on("renderlet.chart", function(chart){
     chart.selectAll('rect').on('click',function(){
       alert("Hello! It works");
     });
 });
```

Now the click event works!

Comment: It's true that this will produce events, but it detects clicks on the brush overlay, not the symbols. So you won't get the information about the points that you would get as the first parameter from an event on the symbol itself.